# WPF PropertyGrid doesn't apply property value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, propertygrid

I'm using [this](https://github.com/DenisVuyka/WPG/wiki)
property control for WPF from Denis Vuyka.

I have the problem that it doesn't apply the new value of a property, if I don't press the TAB key.

So if I change a property in the property grid and then click the OK button, the property has still the previous value.

Sample code to reproduce:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    DataObject dataObject = new DataObject();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        propertyGrid.SelectedObject = dataObject;
    }

    private void OnOK(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Value of test is " + dataObject.test);
    }
}



class DataObject
{
    public int test { get; set; }
    public int test2 { get; set; }
}


<Window x:Class="PropGridTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:pg="http://schemas.denisvuyka.wordpress.com/wpfpropertygrid" 
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" IsDefault="True" Click="OnOK">OK</Button>
        <pg:PropertyGrid x:Name="propertyGrid" Grid.Row="1">
        </pg:PropertyGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Just type a number into property test and then click the OK button.

Does anybody know a workaround for this problem?

This is what I tried in OnOK so far to no avail:

```
        propertyGrid.Focus();
        propertyGrid.MoveFocus(new System.Windows.Input.TraversalRequest(System.Windows.Input.FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
        System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to edit the source code and change the binding on the text editor so that it uses `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`.

To find the area of source that needs updating you can use [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to inspect the control.

Get your application running, fire up snoop, pick your application from the drop down menu on the Snoop tool, and click the binoculars. Now if you hold `shift` and `ctrl` keys while you hover the cursor over the control you'll be able to see its type and all of its properties.

After that you just need to search the solution to find that type and edit the binding in the XAML. Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx) page for info on how to use the `UpdateSourceTrigger` binding property.

Comment: Can you tell me, where is the correct place in source code to do this?

Comment: @MTR: That's a big question. :) I've edited the answer to help you find the right place to make the change. Alternatively you could request the author make the change or file a bug report with him and hope he fixes it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exactly for this grid (I use [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/87715/Native-WPF-4-PropertyGrid)), but I have the same problem there. It seems to be a common problem. Try to remove focus from PropertyGrid to another control before selecting new object ot clearing selected object property. For example:

```
    public static void UpdatePropertyGridObjects(object objToSelect)
    {
        Components.DockManager.Focus();
        Components.PropertyGrid.SelectedObject = objToSelect;
    }
```